# Secured Bluetooth connection Android

Tags: android, security, bluetooth

I am currently developing Prototypes for secure Wireless Communications.
Now I want to create a **secured** Bluetooth Connection with Android.

I have looked up on the Android Developers Website and found a very helpful page that describes how to develop the Bluetooth connection.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

But how can we make it more secure? Any ideas?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: e.g. the message is encrypted or the connection at all. Like in a HTTP connection HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While looking for the solution of similar problem in my app, I have found this blog from code.google.com

It will help all those who are still looking for this problem solution on SO

http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/03/bluetooth-reflection-and-legacy-nfc/

The solution has become very simple now. Just include InsecureBluetooth.java in your project and change 2 lines in BluetoothChatService.java.

```
tmp = InsecureBluetooth.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(mAdapter, NAME, MY_UUID, true);
```

and

```
tmp   = InsecureBluetooth.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device, MY_UUID, true);
```

***Thats it !***